# Let f be continuous and nonnegative

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be continuous and nonnegative on [a, b], and suppose that integration f = 0.Then f(x) = 0 for all x ∈ [a, b]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmjfL.jpg)

Where is the mistake in my answer for this question??

Comment: Why do you think there is a mistake? Your proof is fine except for your notations.

Comment: One I can see is that you use $m$ for two different things (unless you actually mean them to be the same thing, in which case it would be wrong). Also it's "Riemann", not "Rieman".